# Can I speed up the Leonardo bootloader?

Tags: bootloader, arduino-leonardo

Inspired by an example question before beta, can I make the Leonardo bootloader take less that 8 seconds to run? It is very slow and I want to speed it up somehow.

Comment: Can you give us more details about your development environment (IDE you use). Did you burn the bootloader yourself, or did the board came with the bootloader already loaded? Do you have a link to the bootloader code on the net? Also, do you know if this delay is normal of all Leonardo boards? Because 8s seems to be an awful lot of time for a dev board to boot.

Comment: It's the default IDE (this wouldn't make any difference, but OK), and i used the stock bootloader that came with the board.

Comment: What version of the official Arduino IDE? I'm trying to determine the exact bootloader code base. But it won't be helpful because the bootloader you're using didn't come from your IDE. Since it came installed from factory, we may never know which one it is. The only hope is for you to burn the bootloader from your IDE into the board and report the same delay. If you decide to do it, just beware of what you're doing.

Comment: Or someone may give it a try and post an answer assuming one given version of a given bootloader out there. It's possible, but not optimal.

Comment: Are you talking about the time it takes to flash a new sketch with the bootloader, or a boot-up delay on reset before an already flashed sketched starts running?

Comment: @ChrisStratton the boot up delay

Comment: Yes, you can shorten the value of TIMEOUT_PERIOD in caterina.c - see  http://www.leonardomiliani.com/2013/accorciamo-i-tempi-del-bootloader-della-leonardomicroesplora/?lang=en But beware that a shorter value may make it harder to recover if you load a sketch that breaks the USB support.

Comment: @chris - make that an answer, i will accept it!

Answer (score 1):

Detailed instructions on how to shorten the bootloader time of Leonardo etc. are explained [[here]](http://www.leonardomiliani.com/en/2013/accorciamo-i-tempi-del-bootloader-della-leonardomicroesplora/) (as stated by @Chris Stratton).

The crux of the matter was to redefine the timeout period

```
/* ./arduino/hardware/arduino/bootloaders/caterina/Caterina.c */
#define TIMEOUT_PERIOD 8000
```

to a lower value.

However I do not have such issues with Leonardo it boots very fast.
So this issue depends on your environment.

There is also **OptiBoot**, an alternative bootloader that really boots faster [link](https://code.google.com/p/optiboot/):